# ADODB recordset in VBA says excel field is empty when it's not

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, adodb, recordset

I have an excel sheet I need to import in my Access database.
The sheet looks like this:

```
DATE RECEPTION  DENOMINATION        ITEM N°     QUANTITE RECUE
06/01/2010  DVD-Sex & the City  PCR-PA21550167  5
06/01/2010  DVD-Avatar Natie 2  PCR-PA21550209  10
```

I then transfer this file into the database using adodb:

```
Dim rs2 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn2 As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd2 As New ADODB.Command
Dim intField As Integer
Dim strFile As String

strFile = fncOpenFile
If strFile = "" Then Exit Sub

With cnn2
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & strFile& "; " & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"
    .Open
End With

Set cmd2.ActiveConnection = cnn2
cmd2.CommandType = adCmdText
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [PCR$]"
rs2.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs2.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
rs2.LockType = adLockOptimistic

rs2.Open cmd2

While Not rs2.EOF
        strNaam = rs2.Fields(3).Value
Loop
```

Now my problem: certain fields have text in them.
The field value should then be `item0001`, but it's reportedly NULL

When the field has a regular number it works fine.

The strange thing is: there are other text fields in the sheet and they work FINE.

Comment: If you're running this code within Access, why not just use DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be more specific in your Extended Properties portion (and don't omit inner quotes there).

In particular, try `Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"` to allow mixed numbers&text data.

More details at http://connectionstrings.com/.