# VBA to import Excel Spreadsheet into Access line-by-line

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, excel-2010

I'm debugging some code and need to find out where a
`DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , ".....`
fails so I've decided to import it 'manually' line-by-line to see where it falls over.

I suppose something like this is what I'm looking for:

```
mySpreadSheet = ConnectTo(Spreadsheet.xlsx)
while(!mySpreadSheet.EOF)
   get(mySpreadSheet.nextLine)
   SQL("UPDATE MyTable with mySpreadSheet.nextLine")
```

I've tried Googling to no avail. Any help is much appreciated!

---

Additional info:

- The column names of the spreadsheet and the Access table are identical.
- Every data type is nvarchar(MAX) (Or "Memo" as Access calls it)
- The table is a linked table to SQL Server 2008

Comment: Would it be a possible solution for you to export the xlsx file to csv and then read it line by line?

Comment: Limit your spreadsheet to just one record and see if it works at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an ADO connection to your spreadsheet (see [Connection strings for Excel 2007](http://connectionstrings.com/excel-2007)), then open an ADO recordset with that connection (see [StackOverflow: ADODB recordset in VBA says excel field is empty when it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065789/adodb-recordset-in-vba-says-excel-field-is-empty-when-its-not) for example).

Then move through the recordset rows, and create a SQL INSERT statement using the row's values.

```
strInsert = "INSERT INTO MyTable (first_field, second_field) VALUES ('" & -
    rs2.Field(0).Value & "', '" & rs2.Field(1).Value & "');"
Debug.Print strInsert
CurrentDb.Execute strInsert, dbFailonerror
```

That code snipped assumes first_field and second_field are text data types.  If they are numeric, lose the single quotes.

I think that does roughly what you asked.  However, before resorting to code I would check whether the spreadsheet imports cleanly into a new native Access table.  (Also, check whether the data types and constraints on that new table are compatible with those of the linked SQL Server table.)  If that works, maybe try importing the spreadsheet directly into SQL Server from the Management Studio, or whatever tool is appropriate.

Answer (score 10):

ADO works well if you have a well defined sheet layout of your data (HansUp answer).  If you need added control before loading the objects, you can hook into the excel workbook, and then pull out whatever data you like. It really depends on the level of control you need.

```
Public Sub LoadExcelToAccess(xlPath As String)
'uses late binding to open excel workbook and open it line by line

'make reference to Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Model to use native functions, requires early binding however

    Dim xlApp As Object 'Excel.Application
    Dim xlWrk As Object 'Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Object 'Excel.Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sql As String

    Set xlApp = VBA.CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    'toggle visibility for debugging
    xlApp.Visible = False

    Set xlWrk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(xlPath)
    Set xlSheet = xlWrk.Sheets("Sheet1") 'modify to your perticular sheet

    'depends on what your trying to do with the sheet
    For i = 1 To 10

        'quick and dirty:  best to load items into custom class collection, then do processing there
        sql = "Insert Into [Temp] (Col1) VALUES (" & xlSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value & ")"
        DoCmd.RunSQL sql
    Next i

    'make sure to dispose of objects
    xlWrk.Close
    xlApp.Quit

    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlWrk = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Fink. Your program worked well for me. Really great program...

Answer (score 0):

Two additional options:

1. Link the spreadsheet in Access like a table. In Access 2007, go to "external data" pane and select "Import Excel Spreadsheet". You should import to an existing datatable, a new datatable or just link to Excel file. Then, you would work with this new "Excel" table like an Access table (regarded the performance issues, in last case).
2. Try to fix the `Docmd.TransferSpreadsheet` problem. I've been using this method for some years, and it works fine, despite it ought to be a little tricky in some cases (I belive its your case). Please, its worthy if you give more information about your problem with this method, including your Access and Excel version.

I hope I've helped. Good luck.

Comment: A rare downvote, given for outright _wrong_ information. ADO, with the Jet/ACE driver, has no problem treating Excel spreadsheets as database tables. See HansUp's answer, including the links.

Comment: Ok... I was wrong, I never used ADO to connect to Excel. But, mr. @RolandTumble, the other options is not a way to do the task?

Comment: Well, I couldn't remove the downvote--but if you edit your answer I'll be able to then.

Comment: I upvoted. Simply for making me aware of the the `docmd.transferspreadsheet` option. txs.

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting purposes, try linking to the spreadsheet and see what problems you encounter, including data displaying wrong when you view it in datasheet view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try just copying your Excel data to the clipboard and pasting it into your Access table.  Whatever fails will get written into a 'Paste Errors' table by Access.