Creating a table of combinations from singular list
In MS Access I am trying to enable efficient data entry by allowing the user to specify a group of people as a singular list, then extrapolate this into a full list of records covering the range of pair combinations (rather than entering these all separately), excluding matching pairs.
For example, 4 distinct Person_ID are observed at an event together on a given date. I would like the user to be able to enter the list of all the various persons involved, along with the date and other attributes;
PERSONS | LINK TYPE | DATE

Person_ID1 | observed with | date
Person_ID2 | " | "
Person_ID3 | " | "
Person_ID4 | " | "

I would like the macro/VBA to then extrapolate this into a table similar to below;
PERSON1 | LINK TYPE | PERSON2 | DATE

Person_ID1 | observed with | Person_ID2 | date
Person_ID1 | observed with | Person_ID3 | date
Person_ID1 | observed with | Person_ID4 | date
Person_ID2 | observed with | Person_ID1 | date
Person_ID2 | observed with | Person_ID3 | date
Person_ID2 | observed with | Person_ID4 | date
Person_ID3 | observed with | Person_ID1 | date
Person_ID3 | observed with | Person_ID2 | date
Person_ID3 | observed with | Person_ID4 | date
Person_ID4 | observed with | Person_ID1 | date
Person_ID4 | observed with | Person_ID2 | date
Person_ID4 | observed with | Person_ID3 | date

Any strategies or similar examples greatly appreciated!
Still grappling with basic VBA but solid foundation with Access principles

I think this relies too much on user to properly format string with separator characters and line returns so code can parse into discrete fields and records. Really can't beat normal data entry in a properly designed form.

Try using a form for "list entry" and create a feature so it can load a list made in Word or Excel. Use the list more than once by giving it a unique ID

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310582/vba-to-import-excel-spreadsheet-into-access-line-by-line

A simple Cartesian query will do that:
SELECT 
    Observations1.Persons AS Person1, 
    Observations1.LinkType, 
    Observations2.Persons AS Person2, 
    Observations1.Date AS FirstDate, 
    Observations2.Date AS LastDate
FROM 
    Observations AS Observations1, 
    Observations AS Observations2
WHERE 
    Observations2.Persons <> Observations1.Persons
ORDER BY 
    Observations1.Persons, 
    Observations2.Persons, 
    Observations1.Date, 
    Observations2.Date

Output:
Person1     LinkType        Person2     FirstDate   LastDate

Person_ID1  Observed with   Person_ID2  01-02-2024  01-03-2024
Person_ID1  Observed with   Person_ID3  01-02-2024  01-04-2024
Person_ID1  Observed with   Person_ID4  01-02-2024  01-05-2024
Person_ID2  Observed with   Person_ID1  01-03-2024  01-02-2024
Person_ID2  Observed with   Person_ID3  01-03-2024  01-04-2024
Person_ID2  Observed with   Person_ID4  01-03-2024  01-05-2024
Person_ID3  Observed with   Person_ID1  01-04-2024  01-02-2024
Person_ID3  Observed with   Person_ID2  01-04-2024  01-03-2024
Person_ID3  Observed with   Person_ID4  01-04-2024  01-05-2024
Person_ID4  Observed with   Person_ID1  01-05-2024  01-02-2024
Person_ID4  Observed with   Person_ID2  01-05-2024  01-03-2024
Person_ID4  Observed with   Person_ID3  01-05-2024  01-04-2024


It seems the main part is to create a list of Observer/Observed persons.
With assumption that the output table name is Observation with fields as: Observer, Observed, and ObservationDate, a routine as following may help:
SUB Calc(ObservationDate AS DATE)
    DIM dbs AS DATABASE
    DIM rs1 AS RECORDSET
    DIM rs2 AS RECORDSET
    DIM rsOut AS RECORDSET
    
    SET dbs = CURRENTDB
    SET rs1 = dbs.OPENRECORDSET("Persons")
    SET rs2 = rs1.CLONE
    SET rsOut = dbs.OPENRECORDSET("Observations")

    DO UNTIL rs1.EOF
        rs2.MOVEFIRST
        DO UNTIL rs2.EOF
            IF rs1("PersonID") <> rs2("PersonID") Then
                WITH rsOut
                    .ADDNEW
                    !Observer = rs1("PersonID")
                    !Observed = rs2("PersonID")
                    .UPDATE
                END WITH
            END IF
            rs2.MOVENEXT
        Loop
        rs1.MOVENEXT
    LOOP

    rsOut.CLOSE
    SET rsOut = NOTHING
    rs2.CLOSE
    SET rs2 = NOTHING
    rs1.CLOSE
    SET rs1 = NOTHING
    SET dbs = NOTHING
END SUB

